# Show route gives view but not controllermethod

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get my Trips through a category ID. This is all perfectly fine when i do `@tripsByCat = Category.find(params[:id]).trips` in my category show view. However, when i'm moving the same code to my Show method in the category controller i do not get any results.

It seems my "Show" is just not being called.

I raked my route and that's all perfectly fine, I've tried to set a var with some plain text in it to see if that shows up in the show.html.erb and it doesn't. I also tried to do a respond_to but no luck either. Am i missing a bigger picture (yet again, gosh i'm a railsnoob!)?

```
def show
    @tripsByCat = Category.find(params[:id]).trips
end
```

My show.html.erb:

```
<% unless @tripsByCat.blank? %>
    <% @tripsByCat.each do |trip| %>
        <article>
            <h1><%= trip.title %></h1>
            <p>
                <%= trip.description %>
            </p>
            <%= link_to "Zie volledige route", trip %>
        </article>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My category_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @category = Category.new
    end

    def show
        @tripsByCat = Category.find(params[:id]).trips
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your app/views/categories/show.html.erb? What happens when you visit your catagories show page in the browser?

Comment: Please see revised question for the show. The show page in my browser is just empty. If i clear all and, for example, type X <%= @tripsByCat %> X. I will just get X X.

Comment: Are you sure you have trips for that specific category?

Comment: Defining @tripsByCat = Category.find(params[:id]).trips at the top of my view makes it work and loops twice(Two records found)

Comment: Just check if you have two `show` methods in you controller.

Comment: Please see revised question for the controller(It's just a create and a show)

Comment: Sorry for asking too many question, every seems to be right. This will be my last question, can you check from the server logs if you are hitting categories#show when you hit "/categories/1"?

Comment: I'd rather have to answer questions than not getting answers so don't worry about it. My log shows the following:

Started GET "/categories/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-17 10:45:56 +0200
Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
**Removed query because too long for the allowed chars**
  Rendered categories/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: We are missing something very silly, every thing seems legit. I am not able to catch it. Upvoting.

Comment: Argh! Still haven't found the issue. This is so weird!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I had a deprecated categorycontroller which screwed it up. Removing that and copy/pasting the code from one controller to the other fixed it!